# Doing a MongoDB findAndModify query including $addToSet in Casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am both new to scala and cashbah. I am trying to

- update a document if exists (by _id) and create if doesn't exist.
- while updating, update some key values
- while updating, update some keys which values are sets, include some data to those sets.

To achive this, I've written this:

```
DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> uri.toString) ++
      $addToSet("appearsOn" -> sourceToAppend) ++
      $addToSet("hasElements" -> elementsToAppend) ++
      $addToSet("hasTriples" -> triplesToAppend) ++
      MongoDBObject("uDate" -> new DateTime)

    /* Find and replace here! */
    OntologyDocument.dao.collection.findAndModify(
      query = MongoDBObject({"_id" -> uri.toString}),
      update = update,
      upsert = true,
      fields = null,
      sort = null,
      remove = false,
      returnNew = true
    )
```

Documents looked by `_id`, some new items added to `appearsOn` `hasElements` `hasTriples` and `uDate` is updated.

`sourceToAppend` `elementsToAppend` and `triplesToAppend` are `List[String]`

When I run this, I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fields stored in the db can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$addToSet')
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.validateKey(DBCollection.java:1444) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

I didn't get it. What is wrong with this query? `$addToSet` isn't a field, why casbah thinks it is a field? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you using findAndModify rather than an update operation?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I want it to be an atomic operation.

Comment: an update is atomic. findAndMofidy is really updateAndReturnDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason its failing is because the update query is invalid (it wont work in the js shell).

`$set` is implicit for values in the update document, but you can't mix it with other update operators eg `$addToSet`. If you want to mix `$set` with other set operators then you can if you are explicit:

```
val update = $set("uDate" -> new DateTime) ++ 
             $addToSet("appearsOn" -> sourceToAppend, 
                       "hasElements" -> elementsToAppend, 
                       "hasTriples" -> triplesToAppend)
```

You can't `$set` "_id" but as thats in the query and its an upsert - it will merge so don't include it in the update statement - otherwise it will error.

Finally, @AsyaKamsky is right if you dont need the returned document - use an `update` its also atomic.